# Laravel 5.1 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate::allow()

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

When I've implemented this (https://mattstauffer.co/blog/acl-access-control-list-authorization-in-laravel-5-1) 
authorization laravel 5.1 tutorial, I've found the usage of this

```
if (Gate::allows('create-contact')) {
    redirect('hooray');
}
```

And then the framework shows me this error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate::allow()
```

Everything is OK with the dependencies, so that's not the problem, then I found that laravel started to implement this method since version 5.1.11
in this topic at laravel's docs for authorization (laraveldocs/5.1/authorization)
So laravel team is saying in their documentation page that this authorization feature is available since version 5.1.11.

I was getting the same error, so I went to the laravel/framework repository on github (github/laravel/framework/)
and check from version 5.1.11 to 5.1.31 and found that method doesn't exist in the source code.

That gate method is available since version 5.2

You can check both of them here  for v5.1 (github/laravel/framework/blob/v5.1.31/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/Access/Gate.php) and for v5.2 (github/laravel/framework/blob/v5.2.0/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/Access/Gate.php)

So I wanted to share this knowledge with you, but if you find a solution, without upgrading the version of the framework, I would be glad to know.

Thanks!

Comment: This is just an idea (I'm not saying you should do it) but if you really can't upgrade the whole framework to 5.2, could you just pull in the 5.2 illuminate package(s) you need, namely `Illuminate\Auth` https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/auth#v5.2.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's just the result of a typo in your code. The method is called **`allows`**, but your error reports **`allow`** (as in the singular of `allows`):

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate::allow()
//                            This should be "allows" ^^^^^
```

The [`Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/Access/Gate.php) **interface** you're referencing is just a contract that the `Gate` class must implement, just because the `allows` method is not required by it that doesn't mean it is not implemented. It is in fact implemented by [`Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php#L172), which is the actual [implementation that is bound to that contract](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthServiceProvider.php#L68-L72).

Comment: thank you but it was on purpose thinking about maybe it was in a singular way.

Comment: I don't think I really understand. You mean that you want it to be named `allow` (singular)? And using the correct `allows` (plural) doesn't fix the problem?

Comment: I assume that you're Laravel version is > 5.1.11, so please confirm if the method `allows` can be found in the `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php` file. If it's not there then there'a a problem with your packages and your should remove the `vendor` directory and run `composer install` again to make sure the packages are fetched correctly. If the method is there, then please post the code that is responsible for throwing the exception.